# Converting a PHP cURL request to Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, rest-client

I'm attempting to send a NewSubmission to a CRM called LionDesk. The sample NewSubmission code is written in PHP and I need to convert this into Ruby code since I will be integrating this into an existing Rails application.

Here is the code they provide via their docs:

```
$url = 'https://api-v1.liondesk.com//';
$data = array(
    'action' => 'NewSubmission',
    'firstname' => 'Joe',
    'lastname' => 'Smith',
    'comments' => 'API Test',
    'phone' => '555-1212',
    'email' => 'joe@testaddress.com',
    'street_address' => '5937 Darwin Court',
    'city' => 'San Diego',
    'state' => 'CA',
    'zip' => '92025',
    'assigned_user_name' => 'Joe Smith',
    'assigned_user_email' => 'joeassigned@testaddress.com',
    'assigned_user_phone' => '760-123-1234',
    'tag' => 'Buyer,92025,Listings Landing Page',
    'sourcename' => 'Facebook Ad 1',
    'contactid' => '12345',
    'siteid' => '1'
);
$content = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $APIKEY . ":" . "" );  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'X-LionDesk-Id: '.$USERKEY
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$res = json_decode($result);
print_r($res);
curl_close($ch);
```

Link to their docs: https://api.liondesk.com/docs.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've attempted this with gems like 'rest-client' and 'rack', but am really having difficulties interpreting the php code from `$ch = curl_init();` on downward.

Comment: Can you post what code you tried with and what errors are you getting and the `curl_set_opt` are just setting options on the request, with `rest_client` you'd be doing same thing like setting the type of request, post body etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you want to make a post request. more or less like this would be the translation youll have to adapt the headers

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse('https://api-v1.liondesk.com/')

header = {
  'Content-Type':  'text/json',
  'X-LionDesk-Id': 'yourId'
}
data = {  
  action:              'NewSubmission',
  firstname:           'Joe',
  lastname:            'Smith',
  comments:            'API Test',
  phone:               '555-1212',
  email:               'joe@testaddress.com',
  street_address:      '5937 Darwin Court',
  city:                'San Diego',
  state:               'CA',
  zip:                 '92025',
  assigned_user_name:  'Joe Smith',
  assigned_user_email: 'joeassigned@testaddress.com',
  assigned_user_phone: '760-123-1234',
  tag:                 'Buyer,92025,Listings Landing Page',
  sourcename:          'Facebook Ad 1',
  contactid:           '12345',
  siteid:              '1'
}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, header)
request.body = data.to_json

response = http.request(request)
```

Hope it helps. Take a look at this for reference https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

Comment: Thank you all. That was exactly what I needed!

I now understand PHP a bit better as well.